# Problems incorporating an async http request function after a DynamoDb put in node.js lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, slack-api

I have an AWS Lambda function written in node.js that posts a product to a DynamoDB table. In addition to calling db.put I need to make an additional http request using the Slack SDK. Here is a sample I pulled that I would like to run after the DynamoDB call is successful. I am having problems incorporating it with my current code because the sample is an async function and my current code isn't using the async/await pattern.

**Code I am trying to call which is written in an async statement:**

```
(async () => {
  // See: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage
  const res = await web.chat.postMessage({ channel: conversationId, text: 'Hello there' });

  // `res` contains information about the posted message
  console.log('Message sent: ', res.ts);
})();
```

**Below is my current function createProduct which posts a product to DynamoDB (I would like to call the above code as soon as the DB call comes back as successful):**

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');
const { WebClient } = require('@slack/web-api');
const productsTable = process.env.PRODUCTS_TABLE;
const token = process.env.SLACK_TOKEN;
const web = new WebClient(token);
const conversationId = 'C1232456';


    // Create a response
    function response(statusCode, message) {
      return {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        body: JSON.stringify(message)
      };
    }

    // Create a product
    module.exports.createProduct = (event, context, callback) => {
      const reqBody = JSON.parse(event.body);

      const product = {
        id: uuid(),
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        userId: 1,
        name: reqBody.name,
        price: reqBody.price
      };

      return db
        .put({
          TableName: productsTable,
          Item: product
        })
        .promise()
        .then(() => {
          callback(null, response(201, product));
        })
        .catch((err) => response(null, response(err.statusCode, err)));
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using async/await, which will require you to bump your node runtime to 10.x, you can use promises. Since you want to run this AFTER the DDB call is successful, you can do:

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');
const { WebClient } = require('@slack/web-api');
const productsTable = process.env.PRODUCTS_TABLE;
const token = process.env.SLACK_TOKEN;
const web = new WebClient(token);
const conversationId = 'C1232456';


    // Create a response
    function response(statusCode, message) {
      return {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        body: JSON.stringify(message)
      };
    }

    // Create a product
    module.exports.createProduct = (event, context, callback) => {
      const reqBody = JSON.parse(event.body);

      const product = {
        id: uuid(),
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        userId: 1,
        name: reqBody.name,
        price: reqBody.price
      };

      return db
        .put({
          TableName: productsTable,
          Item: product
        })
        .promise()
        .then(() => {
          return web.chat.postMessage({ channel: conversationId, text: 'Hello there' });
        })
        .then(() => {
          callback(null, response(201, product));
        })
        .catch((err) => response(null, response(err.statusCode, err)));
    };
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I were to send the Slack message first, get the response, then make the DB call?

Comment: I believe I would just flip the order right? Make the web.chat call and in the .then() make the db call with a value that was returned from the web.chat call.

Comment: @BlakeRivell exactly right...chaining promises, you would just reverse the order

Comment: I really need to do more research on this, just trying to get something done quick. One final question if you don't mind. How come sometimes I see .promise() and other times we just go straight to .then. What is the point of .promise()?

Comment: the aws-sdk wraps all of their services with `.promise()`...this is because they had callbacks in the past and didnt want to deprecate functionality, so they added promise capability to it.

Comment: I see so it basically creates a promise() and then you call then on it? In what scenarios do you not need to call .promise()?

Comment: only if the service has a promise() function it exports. most of the time, a service will return a promise directly, and hence you wouldnt need to call .promise(). this pattern is typical with aws-sdk, but honestly i havent really experienced it w/ any other dependencies

Comment: @LostJohn one last thing. Do you have any resources where I can learn all about async in general with js and node. I purchased this: https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-nodejs-developer-course-2/ but also wondering if there is anything else I should be looking into. Maybe I need to start with vanilla js. (I have used jQuery AJAX requests up until this point so all of this new syntax is killing me).

Comment: so, resource wise, it basically been an understanding of the JS evolution. so, we started w/ callbacks; i think it is good to live in this hell for some time so you can appreciate change. After callbacks came promises, which are great and I still use all the time, but people still get weary of the callback-like nature. now Async is basically wrapping all function returns in a promise, and extracting the result. I dont know of a great place to learn it, except by trying all three solutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200314/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-lostjon).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call it before your callback without await, and use Promise.all

```
callback(null, response(201, product));
```

And without await, just do

```
const res = web.chat.postMessage({ channel: conversationId, text: 'Hello there' });
Promise.all(res)
  .then(response => {
console.log(response[0])
callback(null, response(201, product));
});
```

Comment: Promise.all takes an array of promises, all you have in the above a single promise being resolved